# How do you call another method from another class with the same name

Tags: java, class, this

I want to call a method from another class using `this.display();`
The problem is, in both classes - there is a method called `display()`

Without changing the names of the two methods, how do I call upon the one in the other class? What is the proper syntax?

The class I am calling the other one from is class: Formula

Comment: Can you should some sample code?

Comment: I'm using StringBuilder to build a string but I want to call upon the other string builder in the other class.

Comment: Do you have a variable which references an object of that other class?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to get the method, if the method was public... not a variable.

Comment: It works just like calling any other instance method of a different instance. Just like you learned in the tutorials.

Comment: Use a reference to the other class, and not `this`.

Comment: Assuming the method you want to call isn't declared `static`, you'll need to have an object of that class before you can call its methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `this`, you are calling the method on the class where you call it.

If you want to call from another method, use a variable.

Example:

```
class A {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println ("a");
    }
}

class B {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println ("b");
    }

    public void example() {
        this.display();
        A x = new A();
        x.display();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B x = new B();
        x.example();
    }
}
```

The output will be:

> b
>
> a

Answer (score 0):

Well `this.display()` will call the method of the current class. You want to write something like: 
`OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass();
 otherClass.display();`